# Why is the WPF XAML Designer not showing in Visual Studio 2022? (Exit code: 80131623)

Tags: wpf, xaml, designer, xaml-designer

Our team just upgraded vom VS2019 to VS2022 and from .NetFramework 4.7 to .NetFramework 4.8.
So with VS2019 and .NetFramework 4.7, the designer was working.

After the upgrade when we try to open the designer, every developer gets an "Unhandlet Exception has occured" with these details:"The XAML Designer has exited unexpectedly. (Exit code: 80131623)".

We also tried our luck with GPT-4 but could not find a solution for this.

Sidenote:

It's also not working with VS2022 and .NetFramework 4.7, but when i create a new Project(.NET6) in the same solution, the designer is working.

Comment: I still haven't upgraded to VS2022 because of WPF designer issues. For example, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XAML-designer-errors-appear-in-VS-2022-t/10299528